# In Java, an expression "new int[3][3]" creates how many arrays inside heap?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I mean it does look like it creates 3 arrays containing 3 group of int elements.
But if we dive deep, shouldn't it be 4?
Because there's an extra array created that is supposed to store the references of each of those 3 arrays.

And the reference of that **EXTRA ARRAY** is what actually gets stored on the variable on LHS.

For ex : int A[][] = new int[3][3];

This means "variable A" contains reference of -> "array of references"[1 reference for 1 array] each of which contains reference of -> each arrays[that finally stores true elements]

So we have 3 arrays that store elements and 1 array that stores references = 4 arrays in total.

Comment: Yes, `new int[3][3]` is an array of three arrays; there are four arrays in total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int[][] a = new int[3][3]` will create 4 arrays in total:

- 3 arrays containing `int` (i.e. arrays holding `int` values), of size 3. The type of these is `int[]`.
- 1 array containing `int[]` (i.e. an array holding references to `int[]` arrays), of size 3. The type of this is `int[][]`.

Note that the notation  `int a[][]` is equivalent to `int[][] a`, but is widely discouraged in Java: it's better to have the full type description in one place and not "spread out" before and after the variable name. The second notation is allowed for "compatibility" with C code, but not really used.